# In DAX how can i pull the inverse of the n value in the RIGHT function?

Tags: powerbi, dax

For example i have a script that looks like this

```
Column = RIGHT(PATHITEMREVERSE(SUBSTITUTE(USERNAME(),"\","|"),1),6)
```

Lets say the value of the input is

Johnson224466

My current script gives me

```
224466
```

I would like the result to be

```
Johnson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using LEFT?

```
LEFT ( USERNAME (), LEN ( USERNAME () ) - 6 )
```